# Linux terminal terminology and command line confusion: pip install versus sudo apt-get and other terminal questions

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pip, virtualenv

`virtualenv --version` or `which virtualenv` gets nothing. I have done these things:

`sudo apt-get update`    --- this automatically puts python3 into the "directory"? I also want help with wording, is this the correct way to say this?

`python --version` shows nothing but `python3 --version` shows python 3.6.5
then I did `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

`which pip` shows nothing and `which pip3` shows `usr/bin/pip3`.

Lastly, I did `pip install virtualenv`.

Now here's where I am confused. It successfully installed virtualenv 16.0.0 but if you do `virtualenv --version` or `which virtualenv` you get nothing. I think this is a fundamental misunderstanding of what `pip` does versus `sudo apt-get/install`. Should I run the command again instead using sudo or is it ok that virtualenv is not found by root? (again missing terminology)

If I chose to leave it the way it is can I run virtualenv still?
I really would like to set everything up correctly this time and only add python libraries to a virtualenv to keep everything clean.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I recommend you use docker instead of virtualenv....

Comment: Why is that? Definitely will consider but can you address any of my confusion about dealing with the linux terminal?

Comment: pip or pip3 only usually only install to the "packages" inside the python or python3 folders. apt-get can sometimes do that too, but it's main use is to install full blown programs and not just python packages. So doing `apt-get` will usually place commands in your "path" which means you could run commands from anywhere, what you reffered to as "root"

Comment: @Amanda.py If you use Docker container, you will have nice convenient way of separating different versions of dependencies. It will also be convenient to share ("ship") your software. And you will learn an industry standard of making software. If you want to learn how to use a UNIX/Linux shell, I highly recommend the book "The UNIX programming environment" available for free with a google search. Learn by doing, it will clear up confusion...practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 1):

`apt` install system packages available to all the users.

If you want to install `virtualenv`, run

```
$ sudo apt install virtualenv
```

and then you'll see

```
$ which virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
```

you can create a virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 venv-3
$ . venv-3/bin/activate
```

and use `pip` inside

```
(venv-3)$ pip3 list
```